# Why am I getting this error involving `_kFIRLoggerInstanceID`?

Tags: ios, firebase, linker-errors, crashlytics, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to upgrade our iOS app from Fabric Crashlytics 3.10.2 to Firebase Crashlytics 7.1.0. I've mostly gotten through the errors, and I've followed a few tutorials, and I've been googling around, but I can't get rid of this error when linking:

```
Ld /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.app/REDACTED normal (in target 'REDACTED' from project 'REDACTED')
    cd /Users/ben_l/Software/REDACTED
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios13.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk -L/Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/ben_l/Software/REDACTED/Frameworks -F/Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/ben_l/Software/REDACTED/Frameworks -F/Users/ben_l/Software/REDACTED/Frameworks/IntuneMAM -filelist /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/REDACTED.build/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.build/Objects-normal/arm64/REDACTED.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/REDACTED.build/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.build/Objects-normal/arm64/REDACTED_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/REDACTED.build/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.build/Objects-normal/arm64/REDACTED.swiftmodule -lc++ -ObjC -DBUILDING_FOR_MOBILE -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreTelephony -framework UIKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -lz -framework StoreKit -lsqlite3 -lc++ -lz -framework REDACTED -framework AudioToolbox -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework CFNetwork -framework EVReflection -framework ImageIO -lsqlite3 -framework IntuneMAM -lc++ -licucore -framework LocalAuthentication -framework nanopb /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.framework/REDACTED -framework IntuneMAM -framework MediaPlayer -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework WebKit -framework REDACTED -framework QuartzCore -framework QuickLook -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework Security -framework MSAL -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreFoundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework AdSupport -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework ReactiveObjC -framework CoreLocation -framework DSI -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreData -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/REDACTED.build/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.build/Objects-normal/arm64/REDACTED_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/REDACTED.app/REDACTED -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ben_l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/REDACTED-gzomtisvvdgyztddvpqujqxqsmjs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Eureka.build/Debug-iphoneos/Eureka.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Eureka.swiftmodule

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_kFIRLoggerInstanceID", referenced from:
      -[FIRInstanceIDLogger logFuncDebug:messageCode:msg:] in FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDLogger_0c879e312576b1b79740d2f19907597f.o)
      -[FIRInstanceIDLogger logFuncInfo:messageCode:msg:] in FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDLogger_0c879e312576b1b79740d2f19907597f.o)
      -[FIRInstanceIDLogger logFuncNotice:messageCode:msg:] in FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDLogger_0c879e312576b1b79740d2f19907597f.o)
      -[FIRInstanceIDLogger logFuncWarning:messageCode:msg:] in FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDLogger_0c879e312576b1b79740d2f19907597f.o)
      -[FIRInstanceIDLogger logFuncError:messageCode:msg:] in FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDLogger_0c879e312576b1b79740d2f19907597f.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone here know how to get past this?

Answer (score -1):

According to the errors, you are missing the components for the platform ARM64.

I would install all the development libraries, VM, etc... for ARM64 first.

Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to install this into an established iOS product. It's been building just fine for years, but gives this error when I tried to update to the newest Crashlytics framework for iOS

Comment: You were using Fabric Crashlytics 3.10.2 to build your iOS App. For building apps, software are used, that have VM for emulation of the different platforms. The different platform support use a lot of space and are modular, so you can install support for one or more architectures. For the error that you shared, it seems that you miss the dependencies in order to build for ARM64 Architecture as it was defined in your initial project.

Comment: Another possibility is that the Logger component that you was using did not support arm64, only arm32. Maybe you was generating for arm32 only?. How old is the app?.

Comment: Apple dropped support for 32-bit ARM architectures in 2017, but our app runs fine on modern devices. The codebase is old, but still runs and is downloadable on the App Store. This shows me that it supports AArch64/ARM64 just fine. You may be right, but if you are, I cannot see it